# ¿Como hacer un NOT IN en LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Queria saber cómo hacer un `NOT IN` en la siguiente consulta

```
 select * from WFRules 
          where (Class = 'DoDesign' or ParentId = 0) 
            and ParentType not in (5,8,9,10,11) 
            and Type not in (5,8,9,11,15,33,34,35,37,38,39,40,41)
```

Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
   var rulcon = (from w in db.WFRules 
                 where w.Class == "DoDesign" || w.ParentId == 0
                 select w).ToList();
```

Intente probar con el contains pero no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debes tener una lista con los valores a ignorar `var types= {1, 2, 3};`

La consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
var rulcon = (from w in db.WFRules where w.Class == "DoDesign" ||
              w.ParentId == 0 &&  types.Contains(w.Type) select w).ToList();
```

De esta forma estas realizando un IN, si deseas realizar un Not IN debes utilizar el carácter `!` para negar la condición `types.Contains(w.Type)`

Comment: el carácter ! iría delante del where? o donde? gracias

Comment: el carácter ! estaría de la siguiente forma: !types.Contains(w.Type)

Answer (score 4):

Esta es una forma:

```
var tipos = new Int32[] { 5, 8, 9, 11, 15, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41 };
var parentTipos = new Int32[] { 5, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

var rulcon = (from w in db.WFRules 
              where 
                (w.Class == "DoDesign" || w.ParentId == 0) &&
                !parentTipos.Contains(w.ParentType) &&
                !tipos.Contains(w.Type)
              select w).ToList();
```

Comment: Gracias funciona bien

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una forma mas elegante y la recomendada incluso para el motor de base de datos cuando haces un query a una BD.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var tipos = new Int32[] { 5, 8, 9, 11, 15, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41 };

var parentTipos = new Int32[] { 5, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

var res = tipos.Where(w => !parentTipos.Any(x => w == x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hola, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio). Ya que no usas el `NOT IN` como se pide en la pregunta, sería ideal que añadieras más información en tu respuesta como por ejemplo en qué consiste lo que haces, cómo es equivalente a usar `NOT IN`, y por qué es la forma más recomendada (¿es más eficiente?¿tiene más soporte?¿es más moderna?). Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones. Un saludo.